# Common variable names in different languages

Tags: variables, programming-languages, coding-style

I see a lot of different styles of variable names used in different kind of languages. Sometimes these names are lowercase and using underscores (i.e. `test_var`) and other times I see variables like `testVar`.

Is there a specific reason why programmers use different variable name styles in different languages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really just the convention for that programming language.

For example, most Java programs use camel-casing (testVar) while a lot of C programs use _ to seperate words (test_var).

It's completely the choice of the programmer, but most languages have "standard" naming conventions.

Comment: It's not even consistent among a single language, at least rarely. There are usually at least two coding styles, often more.

Answer (score 0):

As [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29) says :

Reasons for using a naming convention (as opposed to allowing programmers to choose any character sequence) include the following:

to reduce the effort needed to read and understand source code;[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29)

to enhance source code appearance (for example, by disallowing overly long names or abbreviations).

Also there are code conventions in companies that care about readability of their code.
This simplify the code sharing between programmers and they don't spend time to understand what means variables name "aaa" and "bbb".

Answer (score 0):

There is no real reason. Each language and sometimes even platform can have varying naming conventions.

For instance, in .Net `TestVar` would be seen if it was a public class variable. In C++, `testVar` would probably be opted for. In Ruby, `test_var`, etc. It's just a matter of preference by the community and/or creators.

Answer (score 0):

I urge you to follow language standards.  I work on a team that has had many developers working on the code over the years, and very few standards have been followed.  The majority of our code is nearly unreadable.  I have been working on a standardization project for the last several months.  It has been very difficult to enforce and get buy-in.  I'm hopeful that people will come around as they start seeing the benefits of easy to read code.

For naming conventions/standards keep this in mind:

- Follow team/company standards
- Follow language standards
- Follow the style that the program is already using
- Do whatever you want (Not really - if you don't have standards follow
  your language standards/conventions.)